# Decompostion of gl(2,C) into direct sum of sl(2,C)-modules

Tags: modules, lie-algebras

Source:

Lecture Notes in Lie Algebra by Kailash C. Misra

Let $L= sl(2,\mathcal{C})$ and $V=gl(2,\mathcal{C})$. Then V is an L-module via the action $x\cdot v = xv$(matrix multiplication) for all $x \in L$, $v \in V$. So by Weyl's Theorem V is completely reducible. Find irreducible L-submodules $W_1$ and $W_2$ such that $V=W_1\bigoplus W_2$.

---

I'm truly at a loss here as to where to start.

- I can't think of what L-submodules look like.
- I can't think of a unique (if indeed it need be unique) submodule decomposition of V.
- The only thing that comes to mind is something from topology, where you describe the real plane as a direct sum of the upper half plane and the lower half plane. Only intuition at this point :/

Comment: Please do not down vote without an explanation as to what I can improve about the question...

Comment: **Hint** : you have $L \subset V$, show that it's a submodule. Can you find another module $W$ so that $V = L \oplus W$ ? Can you decompose $L,W$ into irreducible modules ?

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet: I admit that was my first thought too, but under the operatiom here, $L$ is *not* a submodule of $V$, e.g. $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1} \cdot \pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1} = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$.

Comment: Ah sorry I read too quickly.

Comment: @LopeyTall: I did not downvote, but I imagine a reason could be that it's not seen as good practice to post pictures of a question as opposed to typing it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $gl(2, \Bbb C)$ here is really just a confusing way to write the $2\times 2$-matrices with entries in $\Bbb C$. Now a standard simple module on which $sl(2, \Bbb C)$ acts by multiplication from the left is the column vectors $\pmatrix{x\\y}$. Can you find such columns in the $2\times2$-matrices?

**Added:** To spell it out completely, look at

$$V_1 := \lbrace \pmatrix{x&0\\y&0}: x,y \in \Bbb C \rbrace$$

$$V_2 := \lbrace \pmatrix{0&w\\0&z}: w,z \in \Bbb C \rbrace$$

Show that both are $L$-submodules under the given operation (i.e. show that they are subspaces of $V$, and $L \cdot V_i \subseteq V_i$), and that $V \simeq V_1 \oplus V_2$ as vector spaces.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am still a bit lost as to the signifance of those images, x.u, where x $\in$ sl(2,C) and u is the column vector of the aforementioned form. For reference, e.$\pmatrix{x\\y}$ = $\pmatrix{x\\0}$, f.$\pmatrix{x\\y}$ = $\pmatrix{0\\y}$, and h.$\pmatrix{x\\y}$=$\pmatrix{x\\-y}$. I don't see any construction of submodules to built up gl (2,C) given these columns.

Comment: Look at the matrices $\pmatrix{x&0\\y&0} \in gl(2, \Bbb C)$. What happens if you let $sl(2, \Bbb C)$ act on them in the prescribed way?

Comment: Now another thing I'm concerned about after computing these images, how am I to construct a direct sum? Because as I recall, if A is a $m\times n$ and B is a $p\times q$, then $A\bigoplus B$ is a $(m+p)\times (n+q)$ matrix. And so I'm struggling with how to construct a $2 \times 2$ matrix algebra gl(2,C) out of $ 2\times 2$ matrix submodules.

Comment: You're confused, the matrices here should be seen as vectors which are just written in a non-standard way, and $dim(A\oplus B) = dim(A)+dim(B)$. I'll expand the answer.

Comment: My confusion lied in a misunderstanding of the direct sum, this video cleared it up, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qs240Jhl6Rs. Thank you so much for walking me through this!